# Error bars in the same plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following data:

```
data= {{60, 4.92444, 0.156206}, {65, 3.73818, 0.0458043}, {70, 2.19564, 
      0.0539134}, {75, 0.6554, 0.0533553}, {80, 1.0604, 0.0127809}, {85, 
      0.790124, 0.0630165}, {87, 0.594196, 0.109998}, {90, 0.0166927, 
      0.014323}, {92, 0.044787, 0.0246567}}
```

Where the values are `{x-value,y-value,error}`

Question:

How can I plot the `x-values` and `y-values` and the errors as error bars in a plot?. If I use `ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]]]`, I can only plot the x-values and y-values but I do not know how to incorporate the errors as error bars in the same plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform your data using [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html):

```
data2 = {#, Around[##2]}& @@@ data;

ListPlot[data2]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[data2, 
  IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", IntervalMarkersStyle -> Pink]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[data2, 
  IntervalMarkersStyle -><|"FenceWidth" -> 2,"FenceStyle" -> Red |>]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr thank you! This work great ! . Can I ask you how is it possible to change the size of only the error bars from your code?

Comment: @John, try if `IntervalMarkersStyle -> "FenceWidth" -> k` (for your choice of a number k) gives what you need.

Comment: kglr thank you but if I try `ListPlot[data2, IntervalMarkersStyle -> "FenceWidth" -> 800]` (even putting a number like 800) does not work at all to change the size of the error bar. I am interested in the first figure you plotted but it would be great if I can also make a little bigger the error bars of even put them `Bold`

Comment: @John, try `IntervalMarkersStyle  -> <|"FenceWidth"  -> k|>` for different different values for `k`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help! I have accepted your great answer !